# How to find person who has posted maximum number of events

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql. Here is my sql

```
  SELECT LIMIT 1
   users.id,
   COUNT(events.id) AS events_count
  FROM
   INNER JOIN 'events' ON users.id = events.user_id
  GROUP BY
    users.id
  ORDER BY
   COUNT(events.id) DESC
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN 'events' ON users.id = events.user_id
      GROUP BY
        users.id' at line 5: 
      SELECT
       users.id,
       COUNT(events.ID) AS events_count
      FROM
       INNER JOIN 'events' ON users.id = events.user_id
      GROUP BY
        users.id
      ORDER BY
       COUNT(events.id) DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your missing the table name after your FROM clause.  Also the syntax for your LIMIT is wrong.   Look here for reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

```
SELECT 
  users.id,   
  COUNT(events.id) AS events_count  
FROM users
INNER JOIN events ON users.id = events.user_id  
GROUP BY    
  users.id  
ORDER BY   
  COUNT(events.id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Richard the syntax is accurate. Give a man some time to look over his answer. As you did the same when you posted your first revision with the 'user' table missing after the FROM clause. Remember each answer has 5 mins to pretty it up and make it as accurate as possible

Comment: I would withdraw the down-vote but you still missed the table names. Single quotes won't do

Comment: I just wonder that if this query is still correct, when there are 2, or 3 people have the same max event amount?

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT belongs at the end of the query.  Did you also somehow *delete* the `users` table from the query?

```
SELECT 
   users.id,
   COUNT(events.id) AS events_count
FROM users
   INNER JOIN events ON users.id = events.user_id
GROUP BY
    users.id
ORDER BY
   events_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```